# ActiveRecord :has_many associations and === operator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, operator-overloading

Can someone explain me this Ruby on Rails puzzle?

```
 class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :comments
 end

 Post.first.comments.class
 => Array

 Array === Post.first.comments
 => false

 Array === [ 1 ]
 => true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Post.first.comments` is a delegator. It does not give you back an Array directly, but if you do anything with it, it turns into one. This is useful because it lets you do stuff like

```
Post.first.comments.all(:conditions => {:author_name => 'RJH'})
```

without having to inject those methods into the array object, or extending the `Array` class.

Comment: OK, thanks. But is there a way how can I actually find out what class is Post.first.comments if even #class method is delegated?

Comment: you might find this bit of the rails source interesting: http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb

Comment: OK, thanks a lot! Just for those who might stumble upon this thread, quote from the docs: 

"As a corner case, it even removes the +class+ method and that's why you get 'blog.posts.class # => Array' though the object behind blog.posts is not an Array, but an ActiveRecord::Associations::HasManyAssociation.